# Verifying universal property of coequalizers

Tags: category-theory

I'm having some difficulties verifying universal properties of a coequalizer in sets. Given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a set $B$ and $f,g$ being projections from the relations set to $B$, how would one show that $B/\sim$ with the quotient map $q$ is the coequalizer of $f,g$? More specifically, given an arbitrary map $q':B\to Q$, what would be the unique map $u:B/\sim \to Q$ such that $uq=q'$? I was thinking it $u([x]) = q'\circ q^{-1}([x])$ since it is well-defined but I'm not too sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write $\sim \: \subseteq B^2$ as an equivalence relation. Then, as you've said, we have the two projections $\pi_1, \pi_2 : \: \sim \: \to B$, and we want to show that $B / \! \sim$ is the coequalizer of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$.

In a diagram:

[image: The coequalizer diagram]

Here is the place you're getting stuck, I think. We are *not* able to factor an arbitrary map from $B \to Q$! We are only able to factor maps which coequalize $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$. That is, maps $f$ so that $f \pi_1 = f \pi_2$.

But what do we know about $f$ if it coequalizes $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$? It tells us that

$$
(b_1, b_2) \overset{\pi_1}{\longmapsto} b_1 \overset{f}{\longmapsto} f b_1
= (b_1, b_2) \overset{\pi_2}{\longmapsto} b_2 \overset{f}{\longmapsto} f b_2
$$

Put another way, $f$ has the property that if $b_1 \sim b_2$, we must have $f b_1 = f b_2$.

Now let's take an equivalence class $[b] \in B / \! \sim$. If we want the map from here to $Q$ to agree with $f$, we really have one choice available to us: Define $\tilde{f}([b]) = fb$!

Now the coequalizer condition on $f$ is *exactly* saying that this $\tilde{f}$ is well defined.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped me out :)